# What does $D^tf$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-operators

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomial functions on the real field and let $f$ be the linear functional defined by

$$f(p)=\int_{0}^{1}p(x)dx.$$

If $D$ is the differential operator over $V$, what does $D^t(f)$ mean?

As we know, $f:V\to\mathbb{R}$ and $D:V\to V$, so $D^t$ is well defined by means of composition with itself over $V$. However, given that $f\in V^*$, I don't know how to understand the symbol $D^{t}f$.

Comment: In what context did you see this?

Comment: What is $t$ and element of? The naturals?

Comment: Given $f \in V^*$, $D^t(f)$ (or $D^tf$) denotes the element $f \circ D$ of $V^*$, that is, is the function from $V$ to $\mathbb R$ which takes a polynomial $p$ to the real number $f(D(p)) = f(p')$.

Comment: @azif00 Something like that I was thinking about, but I was not convinced because od the order. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given, $V = \mathbb{R}[x]$, the vector space of real polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$. $f$ is the linear functional defined by:
$$f(p) = \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \,dx$$
This means that $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Further, $D$ is the differentiation operator on $V$, so $D: V \to V$.

The transpose of D, namely $D^t$, defined as:
$$D^t:V^* \to V^*$$
$$D^t(g) = gD$$
where $g$ is any linear functional on $V$, or $g:V \to \mathbb{R}$. Also, $V^*$ denotes the space of all linear functionals of $V$ (the dual space of $V$), or $V^* = L(V,\mathbb{R})$.

Now to answer the question in particular, we have:

$$D^t(f) = f(D(p)), \space p \in V$$

$$ \space = \int_{a}^{b} p'(x) \,dx$$
$$ = p(b) - p(a)$$
which follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus.